# discord.py SQLite getting row content

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def tag(ctx, tag):
    sql.execute(f'select tags_name from tags_list')
    does_exist = sql.fetchone()
    print(does_exist)

    if does_exist is not None:
        sql.execute(f'SELECT tags_content FROM tags_list')
        final = sql.fetchall()
        await ctx.send(final[0])
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Tag named `{tag}` doesnt exists!")
```

So the code you see up there is used to get content from the table `tags_list`.

[image]

And the image up there is the table `tags_list`. I am trying to get `tags_content` when I call the command. But for example when I call the command like `.tag test`, I want it to give me `test` because they are in the same row. But instead, it gives the `tags_content` from the first row. So it gives `h` instead of `test`. How can I specify the row I want to get the content from?

Edit: This is what I get when I run the command `.tag test`: `('h',)`

Comment: you have a method named `tag` and  it has an argument named `tag` (not a good idea..) What does the code do with the `tag` argument?

Comment: @balderman `tag` is equal to `tags_name` in the database and it should send the content of `tags_content`. it works as I said in the question.

Comment: As far as I understand the `tag` argument is not part of the sql query. Is that correct?

Comment: @balderman yes, it doesn't exist in the database. it's only for the command

Comment: I think you need to have 1 sql query: `select tags_name,tags_content from tags_list where tag_name = <your tag>` - isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're selecting a row from a SQLite table, you can use `WHERE` to specify the row that you want. For example:

```sql
SELECT tags_content FROM tags_list WHERE tags_name='test'
```

So you can use `tag` parameter to specify `tags_name` when you're selecting the row.

```py
@client.command()
async def tag(ctx, tag):
    sql.execute(f'SELECT tags_content FROM tags_list where tags_name = "{tag}"')
    final = sql.fetchone()
    if final:
        await ctx.send(final)
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Tag named `{tag}` doesnt exists!")
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. but it worked when I changed it into `SELECT tags_content FROM tags_list where tags_name = "{tag}"`.